# How do you backflip in Elden Ring (with PC controls)?

Tags: keyboard, elden-ring

How do you backflip in Elden Ring with PC controls?

I saw a video in which the commentator claimed that if you dodge "while the L2 animation is happening" then you backflip. However, I was unable to duplicate the move.

So, on the PC L2 is Shift+Right-Click on the mouse by default, which is normally a Parry if the person has a shield equipped in the left hand. So, Shift+Right Click results in the shield being swung in an arc, however pressing the dodge button during this animation does not result in a backflip.

Comment: L2 is not just for parry - it's for weapon or shield's skills. What was the weapon/shield that "commentator" were using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out the problem.

You can backflip with a charged R2 by dodging at the same time, but ***it only works with curved or thrusting swords***.